# confusion about numpy where function (Trying to highligt the maximum of a function)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Python 2.7 Spyder 2 Environment,
Used Packages: Pandas, Numpy

This might be an easy question, but I just can't wrap my head around this right now:

I created the following figure and want to higlight with a scatter dot the maximum of the green plot. The values that are earlier than the point intersecting point at y=0 should be ignored.

[image: Figure 1]

I used pandas for the data and tried the following:

```
test=abs(1-(erg['UUmax'][dmin[0]:-1]/ergc['UUmaxc'][dmin[0]:-1]))
plot(erg['t'][dmin[0]:-1]/60.,test)
scatter(erg['t'][where(test==max(test))[0]]/60.,max(test))
```

which results in this so something is clearly off:
[image: what i have tried]

This got me False as an answer so I think my misunderstanding is someweher buried here.

```
test[where(max(test)==test)[0]] == max(test)
```

Comment: I suggest you post a minimal running example.
Otherwise I would recommend [np.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to locate index of max location

Comment: scatter(erg['t'][argmax(test)]/60.,max(test))
seems to work fine. I'm still very confused and would like to know why my code did not work:(